# show hide div from class name pure javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, show

I am working on a video player that launches a video into an iframe within a div overlay.  I want to avoid repetetive code such as onclick=() in every link, and want to avoid external libraries such as jQuery, because jQuery produces an unpleasant flickering screen when my video window is launched.

My problem is that with my work so far, only the first link opens the video overlay.  I (somewhat) understand that the [0] indicates the first element in an array.  Can an array contain an infinite numerical range, or is there a better way to accomplish my goal here?  There will potentially be thousands of videos in these galleries, so listing them one at a time in my script is not practical.

I am still struggling to learn, so a working example would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

My work so far

https://jsfiddle.net/4oomb9rt/

example code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Video Overlay</title>
<style>
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: arial;
}
#vidPlayer {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    display: none;
    color: white;
}
.closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    right: 7px;
    font-size: 50px;
}
.openbtn {
    font-size: 30px;
}
.openbtn, .closebtn {
    max-height: 48px;
    max-width: 48px;
    min-height: 48px;
    min-width: 48px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    line-height: 12px;
}
.vidContent {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 32px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="vidPlayer">
<button class="closebtn">&times;</button>
<div class="vidContent">vidplayer content</div>
</div>
<button class="openbtn">&#9776;</button>
<button class="openbtn">&#9776;</button>
<button class="openbtn">&#9776;</button>
<script>
function openNav() {
document.getElementById("vidPlayer").style.display = "block";
}
function closeNav() {
document.getElementById("vidPlayer").style.display = "none";
}
var opener = document.getElementsByClassName('openbtn')[0];
opener.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    openNav();
}, false);
var closer = document.getElementsByClassName('closebtn')[0];
closer.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    closeNav();
}, false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over element using ClassName and assign event listener.

```
for(var i=0;i<document.getElementsByClassName("openbtn").length;i++){
    document.getElementsByClassName("openbtn")[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        openNav();
    }, false);
    }
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/tj23hy3h/

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the attempts to help me understand.  Particularly thanks to Mohd for the working example

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. You want to make a few minor changes to your javascript.

```
    var openers = document.getElementsByClassName('openbtn');
    for(var i=0; i<openers.length; i++) {
      openers[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
          openNav();
      }, false);
    }
    var closers = document.getElementsByClassName('closebtn');
    for(var i=0; i<closers.length; i++) {
      closers[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
          closeNav();
      }, false);
    }
```

by iterating through all of your openers or closers you can add the listener to each one.

Answer (score 0):

What you're problem is that you'll have to add you event listener to all of the elements of that type so something like this would work:

`var opener = document.querySelectorAll('.openbtn');
Array.from(opener).foreach(function(opener_single){
    opener_single.addEventListener("click", openNav, false);
});`

and then the same theory for the closer elements.

what I'm doing here is I'm getting all elements with the class name of `openbutton` then looping through them in the loop i am then applying the click event listener in which runs the `openNav` function.